# Undefined Constructors in Hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, hierarchy, superclass

I am making a superclass Food with two subclasses: Dinner and Breakfast. Dinner and Breakfast will each have two of their own subclasses, Dinner will have Seafood and ChickenDish while Breakfast will have Cereal and Omelette. Right now I have only programmed Food and Dinner, but when I try to program in main, it says my constructors are undefined.

Here is my Food superclass:

```
public class Food {
private double price;
private int calories;
private boolean vegan;

public Food(double price, int calories, boolean vegan){
    this.price = price;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.vegan = vegan;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public int getCalories(){
    return calories;
}

public boolean getVegan(){
    return vegan;
}
```

}

and here is my Dinner subclass:

```
public class Dinner extends Food{

public Dinner(double price, int calories, boolean vegan){
    super (price, calories, vegan);
}
```

}

To keep this question open-ended, I'm just looking for a more conceptual answer so it can be applicable to other people's questions. How does one create a constructor for a super/subclass and how do I use it in main? Thanks all.

P.S.: I know I could just remove the "public Food" constructor and write "Food x = new Food;" in main but my comp sci teacher requests that you have a constructor in every class: super or sub.

EDIT: My main method is currently:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Food x = new Food();

}
```

}

to which I get "The constructor Food() is undefined". I know that I'm probably missing something/doing it wrong so I'm just looking for guidance in how to actually complete this task.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: You're going to have provide more context because I copy and pasted your classes and am not having trouble coding in my main method

Comment: post code from the `main` method here

Comment: Well, if I do "Food x = new Food();", then I get "The constructor Food() is undefined". I know that I'm probably doing it wrong so I'm just looking for conceptual guidance in how to complete this task with constructors in every subclass.

Comment: You do not have a parameterless constructor, you need to provide the `(double price, int calories, boolean vegan)` eg: `Food x = new Food(12, 1, false);`

Comment: Wow, thanks Nic! Can't believe I missed something that simple. I'll close this question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one type of `constructors`.

One type is `default constructor`

```
public Food(){

}
```

It is called whenever an object of your class is created. In this case, this constructor will be called from main if you create an object of your `Food` class like

```
Food obj = new Food();
```

The one you have defined in `Food` class is called `parameterized constructor`

```
public Food(double price, int calories, boolean vegan){
    this.price = price;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.vegan = vegan;
}
```

This constructor will be called when you create an object of your `Food` class like

```
Food obj = new Food(20.22, 10, true);
```

You need to pass the values as arguments in order to call this constructor.

**Note** that which constructor will be called depends on whether you pass argument values in constructor call or not.

You are getting an error because in your `main` method

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Food x = new Food();
}
```

you are calling the default constructor of your `Food` class but in your `Food` class, you have defined a `parameterized constructor` which expects 3 arguments.

You need to pass those arguments when creating an object of class `Food`
For example

```
Food obj = new Food(20.22, 10, true);
```